# perform segue from collection view inside table view

Tags: swift, xcode, collectionview

I have a table view with a collection view in my 2nd cell.

When a video from the collection view is clicked, i want to perform a segue to another view controller.

[image]

Comment: which swift version you are using? and what is the type of ``self``?

Comment: ok you have added `collectionview` delegate to UITableviewCell, 
Try setting `collectionview` delegate in `cellforrowatindextpath` and put the method in `Viewcontroller`. it will Work

Comment: @mina im using swift 3. self was meant to be deleted, im just trying to push to another controller when a collection view cell, which is inside the table view cel, is selected.

Comment: @hardik.shah im sorry but im learning, how can i do this?

Comment: Ok where you are setting the delegate of the CollectioView?

Comment: you can only performSegue from a controller(UIViewController or UITableViewController). your self is not of a Controller Type right now. you have to pass the didSelect action to your Controller, so it can be able to performSegue

Comment: @Mina how can i do that plz

Comment: @hardik.shah to the tableview cell

Comment: Try in `cellforrowatindexpath` 
`cellvideo.collectionview.delegate = self 
cellvideo.collectionview.datasource = self ` and after that move your method below `cellforrowatindexpath`

Comment: you have to use delegate

Comment: if you don't know how to do that i can explain

Comment: @hardik.shah i dont understand. So add the delates into the cellforrow but what method below that ?

Comment: @Mina i dont, can you please

Comment: @GRattab https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZsk0.png this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's the sample code.

```
class tableViewClass: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, VideoCellSelectionDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VideoCell", for: indexPath) as! VideoCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func didSelect() {
        //performSegue
    }

}
```

the `VideoCell` must have a delegate which is called when a collectionView cell is select

```
protocol VideoCellSelectionDelegate {
    func didSelect()
}

class VideoCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    var delegate: VideoCellSelectionDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegate?.didSelect()
    }

}
```

Comment: i added this code an my collection view is has dissapered

Comment: you just have to add the delegate part in to your project. all others are just sample code, i just wanted you to see how and where you have to use the delegate.